Android - Display number in Status bar, update every 1 min
I have no experience in Android apps, can someone help me write such a small script?
What I need? I need an Android app to run in background and display a number in status bar of my Android phone.
So my app needs this:

I should be able to add URL to my app, example: example.com/returnstring.php
App will run in background and will query that URL (it will return string of 1-5 chars, example: 3.445)
App should display this value in status bar (3.445)
App should repeat step 2-3 every minute

That's all. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Here they said to do this, you should convert text to bitmap and then bitmap to icon and display it in status bar:
How do I show text in android system status bar

You seem to already have found the answer in the linked post. What else do you want to know? Please [edit] your question to clearly describe the specific problem you have. Please provide the code you have so far in the form of a [mre] and explain why the linked post doesn't solve your issue.

The link you posted answers the question how to display the number at status bar. And if you are looking for how to run something in background for every 2 minutes, you can check out Alarm Manager. I guess Work Manager has a minimum interval of 15 minutes which is not ideal in your case.
